# Access value passed in previous step while handling error in Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have a use case where I want to access value passed in previous step while handling error in Reactor code. something like this

```java
return activityRepository.createActivity()
                .doOnNext(activity->{
                    // do something with activity Object
                })
                .someErrorPipelineStep((throwable,activityId)-> {
                    // do something with activity Object
                    return Mono.error();
                })
```

Is there a way to access the activity object inside doOnError or any other error handler.
I cannot use `OnErrorContinue` as the second parameter is of type Object instead of Activity ?

Comment: It's of type object but you can cast it

Comment: that does not help as i cannot access the orifinal methods inside the object .